# how to add "Click" event to SWF file

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe-flash-cs3

i have SWF file. i want to send the user to another page when he clicks the SWF file
1- i tried to wrap the SWF file with  tag but it did not works
2- i tried to add javascript events like "onclick" but it didnot works too
so i think the best solution is to make another SWF file that takes two parameters "hyperlink" and "SWF URL" it will load my SWF and when the user click it it will open the "hyperlink" but i have no idea how to do this

Is there any better solution ? if not do you have any idea how to do this in ADOBE FLASH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHy not stretch a big invisible button across the SWF? If it's not your SWF, then make another flash file with a button over the top, and import the SWF you wanted in the first place.

Comment: i know that this is the best solution but i'm don't know very much in flash do you know how to load the SWF file in another SWF ?

Thanks

Comment: that looks awesome thanks, but how can i change the new SWF dimensions to be the same loaded one ?

Comment: You'll need to change the child SWF size, you can't change an external SWF on the fly, although you can resize the container using Javascript. Give it a good googling